# SSIS Error: The pivot key value "(Can't Convert to String)" is not valid

Tags: ssis, key, pivot

I am trying to use pivot transformation for my table which looks as follows.

```
----------------------------------
PeopleID| Type| AreaCode| Number|
----------------------------------
3553187 | Work| 651     | (651)848-7107
2574269 | NULL| 763     | 763-764-7353
2574269 | Work| 763     | 763-764-7600
3078853 | Cell| 416     | 416-996-2538
```

I am trying to pivot this table using column `Type` as pivot key and `PeopleId` as set key. As there is `Null` value in `Type` column, I get this error message after running my `ssis` package.

Answer (score 0):

Have the NULL value replaced. The column names in the pivot transformation need real string value. It can't be pivoted without it